# Read TXT file with semicolon separated texts using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

sample data in text file is as follows:

**Select * from Table1; Select * from Table2; select * from table3;Select * from table4**

I want to read this text and  break into multiple lines at semicolon(;) and process each line separately. 
Basically each line represents a select query which I need to query one by one against a database

I tried below code but getting error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```
ListData = open(FilePath).readlines()
for line in ListData.split(';'):


data.append(line)
```

Also tried below code but getting error as AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

```
with open(SQLFilePath) as f:
    for line in f.split(';'):
      data.append(line)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the `str.split` method? What code have you tried so far and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I updated question with code that i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use for(). For example:

```
text='Select * from Table1; Select * from Table2; select * from table3;Select * from table4'
for t in text.split(';'):
    print(t)
```

Answer:

```
Select * from Table1
 Select * from Table2
 select * from table3
Select * from table4
```

If read data from file, you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.txt', header = None)
t=[]
for index, row in df.itertuples():
    t=t+str(row).split(';')
```

Console:

```
print(t)
['Select * from Table1', ' Select * from Table2', ' select * from table3', 'Select * from table4', 'Select * from Table1', ' Select * from Table2', ' select * from table3', 'Select * from table4']
```

Comment: Thanks for Anna for your answer, I tried similar solution  but facing issue(I updated question with code sample I tried)

Comment: @CodeStar if it not what you need please add input and output that you expect

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.... is there a way to ignore new line('\") in case if some of the lines ended with new line ?